# Change select tag to input type text

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following

```
    <select id="quantity_select{$item.id}"
             onchange="update_quantity({$item.id}, {$item.quantity});" name="item_quantity_select">
                                        <option name="quantity_1">1</option>
                                        <option name="quantity_2">2</option>
                                        <option name="quantity_3">3</option>
.
.
.
                                        <option name="quantity_more">10+</option>

         </select>
```

My desired behaviour is that when the user selects the option "quantity_more", the select tag disapears and instead a  `<input type="text" value="{$item.quantity}" />` appears. I believe this must be done with javascript,is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: You could have an if block where you'd say if the option where the name=quantity_more is selected, hide the select tag and dynamically append an input at your choice. You could do that easy with jquery or vanilla js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the `onchange` handler for your select and based on the value input by the user, you can create an `input` element and append it to the required place in the DOM.

```
function update_quantity(id, quantity) {
    var selectedOption = document.getElementById("quantity_select" + id); 
    if (selectedOption.value === "10+") {
        selectedOption.style.display = "none";
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.value = quantity;
        document.querySelector('body').appendChild(input); // If you want to append at the end of the body
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't change a select dropdown into an input of type text. I suggest to add an additional input field and set it's visibility to hidden / display to non and on selection of the "more" option toggle the display attribute.

Comment: Why not? `selectEl.remove()` and create the input with the same `value` in its place, and place the focus on it again. Or am I misunderstanding the OP?

Comment: Just what I wrote: remove or hide the select and show another input element. This is not changing the type but toggling two different elements. Refering to the OPS headline question "Changing the select tag ..."

Comment: I guess I took "change the select tag" more liberally than your answer -- I included "remove (from the DOM) and add something else" in my definition. Thanks for the clarification.